# boost::asio checker

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

```
try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

    for (;;)
    {
      tcp::socket socket(io_service);
      acceptor.accept(socket);
     //how do i make a checker here if the client is not sending anything then server send or if the client sending then server recive 
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
```

how do i make a checker, if the client is not sending anything then server send or if the client sending then server recive

Comment: this question is not clear. It sounds like you want a protocol, ex: if the client has not sent `n` bytes in `t` seconds, the server disconnects the client?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not immediately clear.

I would start an `async_read()` with an associated `deadline_timer` set to an appropriate value.  If your timer expires before any reading was performed, then have your server send its data.